# Getting 400 Bad Request during POST string in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, http-headers, bad-request

i have a rest api that accept a String in POST and return an object,

this is the method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/aValue", headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
MyObject getMyObject(@RequestBody String string) {

    MyObject response = myService.getMyObject(string);
    return response;
}
```

now when i call the api from another service for example, if I do POST like this it gave me always 400 Bad Request:

```
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(jsonProvider);

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseUrl + myAPI, providers);

    client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MyObject response = client.post(userId, MyObject.class);

    return response;
```

instead of the working solution i used which is this one:

```
MyObject response = client.post("\"" + userId + "\"", MyObject.class);
```

someone could help me ? thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue 'cause what you're posting is not a valid JSON, yet you indicate that it is in your client-side code. As you seem to pass just a simple string property *userId* you can simply change your mapping to receive plain text by adding `consumes = "text/plain"`,

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/aValue", headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = "text/plain")
public @ResponseBody
MyObject getMyObject(@RequestBody String string) {
```

and have your client send plain text, so

```
client.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

Comment: consumes is not available because we are using spring 3.0.7.RELEASE... and as far as i know we cannpot upgrade the version

Comment: try ommiting it than, properly set content type should be enough